# How to make type area underlined not box in HTML

Tags: html

```
            <form  action="add.jsp" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Order ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="Order_ID"  class="form-control">
            <label>Order Date</label>
            <input type="text" name="Order_Date"  class="form-control">
            <label>Customer Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Customer_Name" class="form-control">
            <label>Customer Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="Customer_ID"  class="form-control">
            <label>Order Amount</label>
            <input type="text" name="Order_Amount" class="form-control">
            <label>Notes</label>
            <input type="text" name="Notes"  class="form-control">
            
            </div>
   </form>
```

[I have this type of box design for input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtnVD.png)

[But I want this type of input area(Underlined)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TA4i.png)

Comment: add css `input { border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black; }`

Answer (score 0):

Added css code in `<input>` changed `border` with `border-bottom`

So will like this, example:

```
border: 0;
outline: 0;
background: transparent;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
```

**Then output will like this**

```css
input.form-control {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.form-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<form  action="add.jsp" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Order ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="Order_ID"  class="form-control">
            <label>Order Date</label>
            <input type="text" name="Order_Date"  class="form-control">
            <label>Customer Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Customer_Name" class="form-control">
            <label>Customer Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="Customer_ID"  class="form-control">
            <label>Order Amount</label>
            <input type="text" name="Order_Amount" class="form-control">
            <label>Notes</label>
            <input type="text" name="Notes"  class="form-control">
            
            </div>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, just need to add CSS and adjust borders.

Run the snippet to see.

```css
.form-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

label {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}

input {
  margin: 8px 0;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<form action="add.jsp" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Order ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="Order_ID" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Order Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="Order_Date" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Customer_Name" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="Customer_ID" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Order Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="Order_Amount" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Notes</label>
    <input type="text" name="Notes" class="form-control">

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i would rather recommend to use a css grid solution. Less coding efford with full responsivness over a float solution which is outdated in modern webdevelopment.

Comment: OP didn't specify the environment he was coding in. It's possible his webpage/application serves a market sector that is tied to older browsers where CSS grid isn't widely supported. - The overbearing question is actually around input borders which the snippet already solves. That being said, I updated the snippet to use CSS grid but in this case, I would argue that it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with `border-bottom` property. But before that, you'll need to reset the default border first using `border: none;`

Follow this -

```html
input
```

```css
input {
  border: none; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

```html
Order: <input type="text" name="Order_ID"  class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

for your oritantion to have the input at the right of the label you can use css-grid. will look the cleanest. For only havin a bottom broder, remoev all border of the input with `border: none;` and add a border at the bottom with `border-bottom`. Note that border-bottom has to come after border as otherwise all border will be removed.

```css
.form-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.form-group input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<form action="add.jsp" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Order ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="Order_ID" class="form-control">
    <label>Order Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="Order_Date" class="form-control">
    <label>Customer Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Customer_Name" class="form-control">
    <label>Customer Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="Customer_ID" class="form-control">
    <label>Order Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="Order_Amount" class="form-control">
    <label>Notes</label>
    <input type="text" name="Notes" class="form-control">

  </div>
</form>
```